# How to make one button with more functions?

Tags: javascript, html, playback, audio-player

I'm trying to make my own radio player, but I do not know how to make one (in this case as "PLAY") that will change to `PAUSE` but after click to `PAUSE` will be show `PLAY` I have this code:

```js
function play() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.play();
}

function pause() {
  audio.pause();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
<input type="button" value="PAUSE" onclick="pause()">
<audio id="audio" src="http://icecast3.play.cz/evropa2-128.mp3"></audio>
```

But I do not know how to edit it to work as I want.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can help

```js
(function() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  var playing = false;
  
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {    
    if(playing) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
    
    button.value = playing ? "PLAY" : "PAUSE";
    playing = !playing;
  }, false);
}());
```

```html
<input id="button" type="button" value="PLAY">
<audio id="audio" src="http://icecast3.play.cz/evropa2-128.mp3" ></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar to the solution provided by @SantiagoHernandez, but since I made the fiddle already:

```
var button = document.getElementById('toggle');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

    if (button.value == 'PLAY') {
        audio.play();
        button.value = "PAUSE";
    } else {
        audio.pause()
        button.value = "PLAY";
    }
});

<input type="button" value="PLAY" id="toggle">
<audio id="audio" src="http://icecast3.play.cz/evropa2-128.mp3" ></audio>
```

The key is to work with a single toggle function, in stead of separate play() and pause() functions.

Also note that I moved the binding of the function to the script as well, rather then doing it inside your html trough the click attribute, since that is considered bad practice.

And the fiddle I talked about:
http://jsfiddle.net/amyh0dxp/

Comment: It is better to use a boolean toggle flag, rather than doing string comparison